# Finding the matrix for a given determinant

Tags: matrices, determinants

In my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424583/formula-for-cointersection-of-three-circles/424764) asking about the co-intersection of three circles, a degree six polynomial in twelve variables was found for a special case. This polynomial has precisely 720 terms, of which exactly half are positive and half are negative.

This makes me strongly suspect there is a 6x6 matrix lurking behind the scenes whose determinant is that polynomial. This leads me to the question: **How can you tell if an expression is the determinant of a matrix, and if so, how can you find that matrix?**

It would be particularly helpful if it could be done for the special case of the polynomial from my previous problem.

Comment: Well, every polynomial is a determinant in a very trivial way. Presumably you want a matrix whose entries are "relatively simple" compared to the polynomial.

Comment: Yeah, I would like the entries to be simple. Ideally, given that the polynomial from the previous question is of degree 6, and the number of terms is 6 factorial (720), then the matrix would be 6x6 with all terms corresponding to one of the coordinates (where there will be some repetition)